# Issue with polymer when creating a custom element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid

I am new to polymer. I am trying to make a context menu like the dropbox menu. Below is my code.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-menu/app-menu.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-menu/app-submenu.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-menu/app-menu-icon-item.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/web-animations.html">

<dom-module id="context-menu">
<template>
    <style is="custom-style">
        :host {
            display: block;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Roboto Mono', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        [hidden] {
            display: none !important;
        }
        #wrapper {
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            /*box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            height: 50px;*/
        }
        .layout-horizontal {
            display: flex;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            -ms-flex-direction: row;
            -webkit-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .flex {
            -ms-flex: 1;
            -webkit-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
        }
        .start {
            -ms-align-self: flex-start;
            -webkit-align-self: flex-start;
            align-self: flex-start;
        }
        .end {
            -ms-align-self: flex-end;
            -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
            align-self: flex-end;
        }
        .fit {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        .fit-btn {
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        .balloon {
            background: #4a7ecc69;
            border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            position: relative;
            top: 50px;
            left: 50px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 12px;
            width: 222px;
            text-align: justify;
            color: #3a3a3a;
            z-index: 200;
            right: 0;
        }
        .balloon .arrow {
            border-color: transparent transparent transparent #4a7ecc69;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px;
            display: block;
            height: 0;
            right: -20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            width: 0;
        }
        paper-icon-button {
            position: relative;
            top: 61px;
            left: 333px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        }
        app-menu {
            --app-menu-selected-bg-color: #cece00;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="wrapper" class="layout-horizontal">
        <div class="start">
            <paper-icon-button icon="favorite" on-tap="toggle"></paper-icon-button>
        </div>
        <div class="balloon" id="animatable" style="display:none" class="flex end fit">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <app-menu selected="0">
                <a class="app-menu-item" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <app-menu-icon-item icon="icons:chrome-reader-mode">News</app-menu-icon-item>
                </a>
                <app-submenu>
                    <div class="app-menu-item" slot="submenu-trigger">
                        <app-menu-icon-item icon="icons:account-balance">Accounts</app-menu-icon-item>
                        <iron-icon icon="expand-more" class="expand-icon"></iron-icon>
                    </div>
                    <app-menu slot="submenu-content">
                        <a class="app-menu-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Google</a>
                        <a class="app-menu-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Facebook</a>
                        <a class="app-menu-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Twitter</a>
                    </app-menu>
                </app-submenu>
                <a class="app-menu-item" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <app-menu-icon-item icon="icons:account-box">Profile</app-menu-icon-item>
                </a>
                <app-submenu>
                    <div class="app-menu-item" slot="submenu-trigger">
                        <app-menu-icon-item icon="chrome-reader-mode">Contacts</app-menu-icon-item>
                        <iron-icon icon="expand-more" class="expand-icon"></iron-icon>
                    </div>
                    <app-menu slot="submenu-content">
                        <a class="app-menu-item" href="javascript:void(0)">John</a>
                        <a class="app-menu-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Harry</a>
                    </app-menu>
                </app-submenu>
            </app-menu>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'context-menu',
        ready: function() {
            console.log("Context menu ready");
        },
        show: function() {
            console.log("Show function call");
            this.$.animatable.style.display = "";
            this.$.animatable.animate([
                /*{opacity: '0', transform: 'translate3d(0, -100%, 0)', offset: 0},
                {opacity: '1', transform: 'none', offset: 1}*/
                {opacity: '0', transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)', offset: 0},
                {opacity: '1', transform: 'none', offset: 1}
            ],
            {
                duration: 400,
                easing: 'ease-in-out'
            });
        },
        toggle: function() {
            this.show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

The menu is something like this.

[image]

The problem is it shows good if it is not embedded into a vaadin-grid cell. When the element is attached in a vaadin-grid then the menu does not show . Can someone please help me out?